# How can i read/write bytes to SD card slot of MC60A?

Tags: sd-card, at-command, quectel

I am working on a clickBoard with MC60 A GSM module from MikroEletronika company.

This clickBoard has two slots: (1) one for SIM card and another (2) for micro SD cards. I have read all the available documentation: AT commands  user guide manual (Quectel documentation) and some code examples (Libstock) and i still cannot find any information about how can i communicate with sd card slot.

The only thing i've found about this topic was on quectel hardware guide:

> The following are the main features of SD card interface: Only support 1bit serial mode; Not support the SPI mode for SD memory card; Not support multiple SD memory cards ;Not support hot plug; The data rate up to 48MHz in serial mode; Support memory cards with maximum capacity up to 32GB;

From this i assume it is a serial communication. So, with the info i know, the two questions i have are:

(1) Can i write/read bytes with the usage of AT commands? If yes, which AT commands?

(2) It is necessary any specific format for micro SD card (FAT, exFAT, FAT32 or NFTS) ?

Best regards, 
Ricardo

Comment: There exist no standardized AT commands for accessing a SD card, however the manufacturer is free to add its own non-standard commands for this. The point is that you **MUST** get hold of the *MC60 A GSM module's* AT command documentation. Nothing else will be useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

I sent an e-mail to quectel manufacturer and they sent me a specific document for FILE AT commands. [Here](https://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_GSM_FILE_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.4.pdf). For some reason, neither MikroEletronica or quectel have this file available on MC60 datasheets.